Dual of compact operator restricted on closed unit ball is weak$^*$ to norm continuous
Assume $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces and denote by $B^*\subset Y^*$ the closed unit ball. $A\in L(X,Y)$ is compact. How to show that $A^*|_{B^*}:B^*\to X^*$ is continuous with respect to the weak$^*$ topology on $B^*$ and the norm topology on $X^*$?

Let $y_a^* \xrightarrow{w^*} y^*$. You have to show that $A^*y_a^* \to A^*y^*$ in the norm of $X^*$. Since $A^*$ is $w^*$-to-$w^*$ continuous you have that $A^*y_a^* \xrightarrow{w^*} A^*y^*$.
Can you now use compactness of $A^*$ to show that $A^*y_a^* \to A^*y^*$ in norm? What happens when $A^*y_a^* \not \to A^*y^*$?
